# Evaluating Expression in java

Tags: java, stack

I am getting output impossible.
but it must be possible.
when i check at  the editor it shows that that the case is always true
i.e last three cases of switch.

```
public String isPossible(String express) {
    char a = ' ';
    char b = ' ';
    boolean flag = true;
    Stack<Character> pile = new Stack<Character>();
    char [] array = express.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
        a = array[i];
        switch (a) {
            case '(':
                pile.push(a);
                break;
            case '{':
                pile.push(a);
                break;
            case '[':
                pile.push(a);
                break;
            case ')':
                b = pile.pop();
                if (b != '(' || b != 'X')
                    flag = false;
                break;
            case '}':
                b = pile.pop();
                if (b != '{' || b != 'X')
                    flag = false;
                break;
            case ']':
                b = pile.pop();
                if (b != ']' || b != 'X')
                    flag = false;
                break;
        }

    }
    if (flag == false || pile.size() % 2 != 0)
        return "impossible";
    else
        return "possible";
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Merge a = new Merge();
    System.out.println(a.isPossible("(())"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is incorrectly using the `||` (or) operator.  It is always true that `b` is not `'('` or it's not `'X'`.  You want `&&` (and).

Replace

```
if(b!='(' || b!= 'X')
```

with

```
if(b!='(' && b!= 'X')
```

and similarly for the other `if` conditions in the case statements.